# Find day values in bigint date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

This query is working good.

```
select  DATENAME(DW,getdate()) AS [Weekday]
```

My Problem is suppose I give input values like

```
select  DATENAME(DW,InvoiceDate) AS [Weekday] from store;
```

is not working in SQL-Server 2008 R2.

Column datatype is `BIGINT`, column values below

```
InvoiceDate

20130925
20130926
20130927
20130928
20130929
20130930
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, why on earth are you storing dates as `BIGINT`?!

Date fields should be stored as dates, otherwise you could end up inserting invalid dates and you'll have trouble doing basic date calculations, as per now.

To answer your question, you'll need to `CAST` the `InvoiceDate` field, firstly to a VARCHAR, then to a `DATE` type:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST(CAST(InvoiceDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATE)) AS [WeekDay]
    FROM Store;
```

Comment: Are you sure CAST() knows how to convert his BIGINT correctly to DATE?

Comment: Good point, CAST to VARCHAR first

Comment: No. It's not "working good", it's a workaround. If you want your system to "work good", fix it by answering Mark's first question.